# Swap second and prelast element from a list prolog

Tags: prolog, swap, element

Well, for the last few hours, I've been trying to swap the second item of a given list with its penultimate item (the second last). Give the list `[a,b,c,d,e,f]`, I want to get `[a,e,c,d,b,f]`. For example:

```
correct(List1,X,List2)
?-correct([a,y,b,c,d,e,x,f],x,List2).
List2[a,x,b,c,d,e,y,f].
```

- `List1` is the list i got to swap second and penultimate (second last) element.
- `X` is the penultimate element.
- `List2` is the new list with the swapped elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for lists of length `4` or greater:

```
correct( [H1|[H2|T1]], X, [H1|[X|T2]] ) :-
   reverse(T1, [HR|[X|TR]]),
   reverse([HR|[H2|TR]], T2).

| ?- correct( [1,2,3,4,5,6], X, L ).

L = [1,5,3,4,2,6]
X = 5

(1 ms) yes
| ?-
```

You can include the shorter cases, if that's the intention, by adding two more predicates, bringing the solution to:

```
correct( [A,X], X, [X,A] ).
correct( [A,X,B], X, [A,X,B] ).
correct( [H1|[H2|T1]], X, [H1|[X|T2]] ) :-
   reverse(T1, [HR|[X|TR]]),
   reverse([HR|[H2|TR]], T2).
```

Comment: thank you alot for your fast answer.Now i understand how i can solve this problem.

Comment: The predicate `correct/2` can be defined such that the input list is only traversed once and without calling the `reverse/2` predicate twice (which, btw, is not a standard predicate although is often defined in a library of utility list predicates).

Comment: @PauloMoura I agree, although `reverse/2` is defined in GNU Prolog and SWI Prolog. This was a "simple" if less efficient approach.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions posted by mbratch and CapelliC both fail for the following base case:

```
?- correct([a,y], X, List2).
false.
```

The following solution takes care of this base case and doesn't rely on list predicates that may or may not be available. It traverses the list once and is more efficient than the other two solutions:

```
correct([PreLast, Second], Second, [Second, PreLast]) :-
    !.
correct([First, Second, Last], Second, [First, Second, Last]) :-
    !.
correct([First, Second| InRest], PreLast, [First, PreLast| OutRest]) :-
    correct_aux(InRest, Second, PreLast, OutRest).

correct_aux([PreLast, Last], Second, PreLast, [Second, Last]) :-
    !.
correct_aux([Other| InRest], Second, PreLast, [Other| OutRest]) :-
    correct_aux(InRest, Second, PreLast, OutRest).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- correct([a,b], X, List).
X = b,
List = [b, a].

?- correct([a,b,c], X, List).
X = b,
List = [a, b, c].

?- correct([a,b,c,d], X, List).
X = c,
List = [a, c, b, d].

?- correct([a,b,c,d,e], X, List).
X = d,
List = [a, d, c, b, e].
```

Comment: Nice solution, Paulo (+1). I think you left out the list of length 3 case, though.

Comment: Good catch. The easiest solution seems to be to also add a list of length three as a second base case. I edited the code accordingly. But can this solution be simplified? All those cuts bother me.

Comment: This answer terminates also for `correct(L,X,[a,b,c,d,e])`. The cuts, though, cause incompleteness: `correct(L,X,L)` has more than one answer.

Comment: @false, as it turns out, for Paulo's solution to work, a cut is only needed at the end of the first `correct_aux` clause. All of the other cuts can go away.

Comment: @mbratch: All cuts have to go away to show all answers for `correct(L,X,L)`.

Comment: @false, ok, I see. Removing all but one gave a few more solutions but not all. Removing the last cut gives all of the solutions, but then causes an infinite recursion for the `correct(L,X, [a,b...])` case.

Comment: @mbratch: Above solution without cuts terminates for: `correct(L,X,[a,b,c,d,e,f]).` I cannot see a case where it does not terminate for a list in the last argument. Do you?

Comment: @false, indeed that appears to be true. I must have done done something wrong the prior time I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

another available builtin is append/2:

```
3 ?- [user].
correct(L, X, R) :- append([[A,B],C,[X,E]], L), append([[A,X],C,[B,E]], R).
|: 
% user://2 compiled 0.02 sec, 2 clauses
true.

4 ?- correct( [1,2,3,4,5,6], X, L ).
X = 5,
L = [1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6] ;
```

I like mbratch one (+1), maybe this solution is more intuitive.

Comment: This is nice, CapelliC, I was reaching for an `append` solution and you found it. :)